# How to make a request to a website with TcpClient

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am trying to make a request to a website with a TcpClient, but I can't get it to work. First I make a connection with the remoteHost and write the request headers that are in the requestStr-variable. After that I am reading from the remote stream and expecting to get a response, but I don't get anything. I use the code from the while loop also for receiving request headers from a browser that uses my app as a proxy and that works fine.

The Eol variable is `\r\n`.

The requestStr variable is:

```
GET http://steam.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: steam.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: nl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

The code snippit:

```
TcpClient remoteClient = new TcpClient(request.GetRemoteHost(), 80);
byte[] remoteRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestStr);
NetworkStream remoteStream = remoteClient.GetStream();
remoteStream.Write(remoteRequest, 0, remoteRequest.Length);
remoteStream.Flush();

int j;
string remoteStr = "";
byte[] remoteBuffer = new byte[App.BufferSize];
recvRequest = true;
while (recvRequest && (j = remoteStream.Read(remoteBuffer, 0, remoteBuffer.Length)) != 0) {
    string receivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(remoteBuffer, 0, j);

    if (receivedData.IndexOf(Eol) < 0) {
        remoteStr += receivedData;
    } else {
        remoteStr += receivedData.Substring(0, receivedData.IndexOf(Eol + Eol));
        recvRequest = false;
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(remoteStr);
```

Comment: Are you doing this as a learning exercise or are you using `TcpClient` as you thought it best suited for the job?  If the latter, you might want to take a look at something like [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx). or [`WebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this for an assignment on school. (So learning)

Comment: Fair enough!  To be clear, do you have a blank line (still terminated with `\r\n`) at the end of your request string?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I feel kinda stupid now, when I read an incoming request from the browser on my proxy, I put the content of it in the string but not with the 2 \r\n at the end. I added them again to the requestStr and I get a response. Thanks for getting me to realize it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the request you're sending, you're not including [a blank line](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) (still terminated with \r\n) at the end of it.  This marks the end of the headers so the server knows it has received them all and can process the request.